# Replace all tds following a specific td which has a classname with new td's with inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html code:

```
<a id="addNewItem" onclick="addNewItem()" class="btn">Add New Item</a>

<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td class="purpose-class">test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td class="purpose-class">test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to achieve is when I click on the button and afterwards when I click on the desired row to replace all the td's following the .purpose-class with new td's which have inputs in between them.

The js function:

```
function addNewItem() {

  $tr = $('table tbody tr');

  var newItem='<td><input type="text" value=""></td>'+
               <td><input type="text" value=""></td>'+
               <td><input type="text" value=""></td>';


 $tr.click(
    function() {
      $(this) somehow and $('td.purpose-class').nextAll().replaceWith(newItem);
    }
);
```

So the expected result when I click on a row would be the following:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td class="purpose-class">test</td>
   <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
   <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
   <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td class="purpose-class">test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basic idea using remove() and append()

```js
var $tr = $('table tbody tr');

var newItem = '<td><input type="text" value=""></td>' +
  '<td><input type="text" value=""></td>' +
  '<td><input type="text" value=""></td>';


$tr.on("click", function() {
    var cell = $(this).find('td.purpose-class');
    if (!cell.is(".added")) {
      cell.addClass("added")
      cell.nextAll().remove();
      $(this).append(newItem)
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td class="purpose-class added">test</td>
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td class="purpose-class">test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the snippet might help you

```js
function addNewItem() {

  $tr = $('table tbody tr');

  var newItem='<td><input type="text" value=""></td>'+
               '<td><input type="text" value=""></td>'+
               '<td><input type="text" value=""></td>';

 $tr.click(function() {
      $('td.purpose-class').nextAll().replaceWith(newItem);
    }
);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="addNewItem" onclick="addNewItem()" class="btn">Add New Item</a>

<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td class="purpose-class">test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td class="purpose-class">test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

See below code

```js
$('#addNewItem').click(function(){
  $tr = $('table tbody tr');
  var newItem='<td><input type="text" value=""></td>';
  $tr.click(function() {
    $(this).find('td.purpose-class').nextAll().replaceWith(newItem);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="addNewItem" href="#" class="btn">Add New Item</a>

<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td class="purpose-class">test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td class="purpose-class">test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```